# The difference between <group> element and <job-group> element in quartz_jobs.xml

Tags: triggers, quartz.net

I'm a newbie in Quartz.NET . 
I'm confused with the  and  element functionality.
What is the different between  and  element inside  element?
Thank you in advance.

```
<job>
  <job-detail>  
    <name>MyJob</name>
    <group>MyJobs</group>
    <description>Logs a message to the application log</description>
    <job-type>JobScheduler/job-type>
    <volatile>false</volatile>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <recover>false</recover>
    <job-data-map>
      <entry>
        <key>MessageToLog</key>
        <value>Hello from MyJob</value>
      </entry>
    </job-data-map>
  </job-detail>
  <trigger>
    <cron>
      <name>MyJobTrigger</name>
      <group>MyJobs</group>
      <description>A description</description>
      <job-name>MyJob</job-name>
      <job-group>MyJobs</job-group>
      <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
  </trigger>
</job>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the trigger section, group is the name of group that you want to place the trigger in, whereas job-group is the name of the group that the job has been created in. Remember in other to identify the job you need to know both its name and group.

In your example, you are using the same name for both groups, but that doesn't have to be case.

It could be possible to create jobs and group them by department, eg Marketing, Development, Support etc. But you could create triggers in group based on the team member.

In this case you could have a job called MyJob in a group called Development
And a trigger called MyJobTrigger in a group called user2709630.

When you create the trigger, you need to say what group it belongs to, but also which job it relates to.

So your xml becomes something like.

```
<job>
  <job-detail>  
    <name>MyJob</name>
    <group>Development</group>
    <description>Logs a message to the application log</description>
    <job-type>JobScheduler/job-type>
    <volatile>false</volatile>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <recover>false</recover>
    <job-data-map>
      <entry>
        <key>MessageToLog</key>
        <value>Hello from MyJob</value>
      </entry>
    </job-data-map>
  </job-detail>
  <trigger>
    <cron>
      <name>MyJobTrigger</name>
      <group>user2709630</group>
      <description>A description</description>
      <job-name>MyJob</job-name>
      <job-group>Development</job-group>
      <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
  </trigger>
</job>
```